# Is there any way django does not save the file uploaded with form

Tags: python, django

I have the django form where user attach the files, but I am extracting the pdf form data from the file itself so I don't want to save the file.

But when I save the form then file automatically gets saved. Is there any way to prevent the file from being saved?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a file is being uploaded to your server, django handles the uploaded file depending on the `FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLER` you specify. By default, they are:-

```
("django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler",
 "django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler",)
```

which means that the file object is in your server's memory until `form.save()` (where the `form` object contains your uploaded file) is called. Once it is called, the file object is written into your filesystem based on what you specified in that file field's `upload_to` attribute.

What I would do to prevent this uploaded file from being written into your filesystem would be to assign this file object to a variable without calling `form.save()`. Like this:-

```
uploaded_file = request.FILES['file']
```

and we can deliberately not assign `request.FILES`, like this:-

```
form = MyModelFormWithFileField(request.POST, None)
```

Since you have `uploaded_file` variable assigned, you can now do whatever you wish to it without writing it into the filesystem.

And since your `form` instance do not have `request.FILES` assigned, `form.save()` will not write your form data into the filesystem.